# How do I subset a data frame in R based on the next occurrence?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Allow me to elaborate. Basically, I have a data frame with 4 columns, and one of the columns have NA's in them. When NA's do occur, they always occur in groups. I am looping through this data frame row by row, looking at the column. What I want to do is as soon as I find a NA, I want to subset the data frame from that row to the row with the last occurrence of a NA, before I reach a normal value.

So for example, let's say we look at my data frame df:

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
R1 2  1  2  1  0  0
R2 2  2  1  1  0  0
R3 0  0  1  1  2  1
R4 2  2  1  NA 0  0
R5 0  0  1  NA 2  1
R6 0  0  1  NA 2  1
R7 2  2  1  NA 0  0
R8 0  0  1  1  2  1
R9 2  1  2  1  0  0
R10 2  2  1  1  0  0
R11 0  0  1  1  2  1
R12 2  2  1  NA 0  0
R13 0  0  1  NA 2  1
R14 0  0  1  NA 2  1
```

As I then loop through df row by row, I come accross the first NA in row 4, I then want to subset df from row 4 to row 7, which is where the last NA is in this particular group of NA's.

Subset:

```
R4 2  2  1  NA 0  0
R5 0  0  1  NA 2  1
R6 0  0  1  NA 2  1
R7 2  2  1  NA 0  0
```

Notice that I did not subset all of the rows with NA, only the current "group" of NA I was looking at. I did not subset from rows 12-14.

How do I do this?

Comment: You'd like each set of these rows (with consecutive NA rows) in a list? (assuming you have more rows where this can occur more than once).

Comment: Also is it only C4 that has NAs always?

Comment: @Arun, I'd like to subset into a new data frame, so looking at the example above, as soon as I come across the NA in row 4, I would want to find the last NA in in the stretch of NA's, and then subset accordingly. So basically i'd want my subset to be: subset = df[4:7,]. The problem is to find out the last row to go till.

Comment: yes, I get that. but what if your data had 9th and 10th rows as well with NA in column C4.. Do you want the result to be merged with the first subset or do you want it to be another data.frame within a list?

Comment: @Arun, hopefully my edit clarify's your question. I don't want to store all of the subsets in a list because after I get one subset, I will do something with it and then I don't need it anymore, so there is no need to store all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to store the ids of consecutive `NA`s in a list and then subset however you want later (using `lapply` or explicit `for-loops`)

```
isna <- is.na(df$C4)
idx <- which(isna)
rr <- rle(isna)
idx <- split(idx, rep(seq(sum(rr$values)), rr$lengths[rr$values]))
# $`1`
# [1] 4 5 6 7

# $`2`
# [1] 12 13 14
```

They correspond to row numbers... Now, you can subset:

using `lapply`:

```
oo <- lapply(idx, function(ix) {
    this_sub <- df[ix, ]
    # do whatever you want
})
```

using `for-loop`:

```
for (i in seq_along(idx)) {
    this_sub <- df[idx[[i]], ]
    # do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a data frame containing all rows that have NA in column 'C4' you do:

```
df[which(is.na(df$C4)), ]
```

where df is your data frame.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This would seperate all of the NA's, but in my data frame the rows are arranged in time order, and the NA's occur in various groups, they aren't in one continuous line. This is why I only want to find the last NA in the group of NA's i am looking at. I'll edit my table above to give you a better understanding